# Convert User Settings to Social Network Link in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook

I'm a newbie to programming, so the answer may be easy, I just can't figure it out.  I'm using Rails 3, and for my users, I want them to be able to specific their social network info and then based on that show the matching icons with links to their pages.  For example, a user would specific the URL to their Facebook page and then on their profile (on my site), it would show a Facebook icon linked to their page.

I may be taking a bad approach by asking the user to provide their whole url, as opposed to just an ID, but I'm thinking about Facebook where some people have user names, some show the numerical id in the url still.  So I was thinking it can get confusing to tell people how to find their ID.  Maybe some will have an opinion on this, also.

Right now, my links look like this, but they're wrong:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("twitter.png"), "@user.twitter" %>
```

Whether I try:

- "@user.twitter"
- @user.twitter
- "#@user.twitter"

it doesn't work.  It wants to append the string in @user.twitter to the base url of the site.  Can someone please help me figure out how to fix this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an application that links to facebook with

```
<%= link_to image_tag("facebook.png"), @user.facebookid %>
```

When you click on your link what happens?

Are you asking for the full url? (http:// etc)

Comment: Thanks Steve.  When I try it, it always puts me URL in front of what's in the field - like example.com/twitter.  On a sidenote do u recommend just going with the Id?  If so, where does a user find their fb id?  Thanks!